# How to make skewed containers respect boundaries of parent

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Below I have an Orange container with a stack of two containers (Blue and Purple) as children. Both of the children have a much larger width than the parent. The Blue child is automatically clipped (which I would expect). However, when I add a transform skew to the purple, the skewed parts go outside of the parent container. Any idea how to fix this? So that the skewed purple container remains within the bounds of the orange parent?

[image]

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 150.0,
      color: Colors.orange,
      alignment: Alignment(-1, -0.5), // where to position the child
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          // Main Face
          Container(
            width: 500.0,
            height: 50.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
            child: Transform(
              alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
              transform:
                  Matrix4.skewX(0.7), // skew x will not go out of x bounds
              child: Container(
                width: 500.0,
                height: 50.0,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add `ClipRect` between `Container` and `Stack`?

Comment: sure, your welcome